# Universal link with branch.io doesn't work with iPhone when it works with iPad

Tags: ios, swift, branch.io

My app is in production now, and within my app I create a Universal link using **branch.io** and share it to other users using for example iMessage. Example link below I got from my friend is below:

- [image]

I have the app from App Store installed on both devices: iPad and iPhone. Now the above link I tap on iPad and everything is fine. My App is opened I can catch the link.

But when I tap it on iPhone the result is following:

[image]

Why? Shouldn't it work the same way on both iPad and iPhone? I do not know what is wrong here.

This is how I defined it in dashboard of branch.io:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering a new behavior introduced with iOS 10.3. The pop-up you are seeing will open the app now only if the user responds to the pop-up alert affirmatively. You must have not yet updated your iPad.

There is an unexpected issue with this new behavior beyond the obvious:
if the user taps "Cancel" on the pop-up alert, he or she will be stuck on a blank page in Safari. To improve this experience I recommend setting the $ios_passive_deepview parameter to the key of a Deepview of your choice (branch_default is the default, I believe).

Comment: so if it is by default and should help... why it doesnt help?